# PDO insert data through transaction method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an import books function to insert more than 5000 rows at once, I did some research and did this one but some other places I saw a different kind of methods to insert without looping and execute this. is my code got any trouble with the performance of app

```
public function importBooks($data, $no_of_rows)
{
    try {
        // Start transaction
        $this->db->beginTransaction();

        // Init query
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO books_pre (title, author, publication, container, tmp_no, created_by, created_at) VALUES (:title, :author, :publication, :container, :tmp_no, :created_by, now())');

        for ($i=2; $i<=$no_of_rows; $i++) {
            // Bind values
            $this->db->bind(':title', $data[$i]['B']);
            $this->db->bind(':author', $data[$i]['C']);
            $this->db->bind(':publication', $data[$i]['D']);
            $this->db->bind(':container', $data[$i]['E']);
            $this->db->bind(':tmp_no', $data[$i]['A']);
            $this->db->bind(':created_by', $_SESSION['user_id']);

            // Execute query
            if (!$this->db->execute()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Commit data
        $this->db->commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->db->cancelTransaction();
        echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to skip the first two rows?

Comment: i don't want to skip any of those, but I have doubted this way has any performance issues

Comment: why your $data indexing starts from 2 then?

Comment: thats one i'm inserting my data from excel sheet, so i dont want to insert the heading names on database

Comment: so you *are* skipping the first two rows?

Comment: yes I am skipping, i am skipping only the 1st row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all right from the performance point of view.

But again, you are doing the double work with your homegrown wrapper. For the life of me I won't understand a wrapper that makes your life *harder*.

So again, a code with vanilla PDO instance `in $this->db`

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO books_pre 
    (title, author, publication, container, tmp_no, created_by, created_at) 
    VALUES (:B, :C, :D, :E, :A, :user_id, now())');

try {
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
    foreach(data as $i => $row) {
        // skip the first two lines
        if ($i == 0 or $i == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        $row['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $stmt->execute($row);
    }
    $this->db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->db->rollback();
    throw new $e;
}
```

Given you already have an associative array we can use its keys as placeholder names.

PDO's `execute()` method can accept an associative array with data, for example

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(['id'] => $id);
```

As you can see, we are sending an array directly into execute(), which  keys that must match placeholder names. Given your array already have keys, I just used them as placeholder names in the query.

However, it'a a matter of taste and you can keep use your bind() calls instead.

An important note, there should be **no such thing** like `echo "Failed: "` in your code. Always just throw an error and let it be echoed by PHP.

On a side note, a comment like this

```
    // Start transaction
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
```

makes very little sense. Do not write comments that just duplicate a code below. Use comments to explain something not that obvious.

Comment: can u bit it explain me in words that, whats happening on foreach and inside of it

Comment: what happens on foreach is explained on the respective manual page, I believe,  as of the inside I added the explanation.